The package org.apache.jena does not exist
I'm trying to query RDF data from an RDF file using SPARQL CONSTRUCT queries in Eclipse IDE.
I try to import this: import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.*; in Eclipse
I get the error:

The package org.apache.jena is not accessible

When browsed the folder ../apache-jena-2.10.0/javadoc-arq/org/apache/jena directory it contains only

(altas, web, riot)

I have added all user librairies of Apache Kena in the project in Eclipse IDE.
I tried different versions of Apache Jena, but it does not work.

apache-jena-2.10.0 is very old (2013-02-24). The package naming structure was different.The current version is 5.0.0. Use maven to manage your dependencies.

i changed this version to 5.0.0 , and i use maven to manage the dependencies , but when i try to run the java file , i get this : the editor does not contain a main type .

We can't see the file but the error message suggests there is no "public static void main(String...args)" function.
